# return all rows even if relationship is empty in wherehas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables Posts and Categories and I am trying to display them in an accordion. Categories and Posts inside each category. I was able to do it using Category::with('posts').

The problems (where I need help) is when I am trying to filter the posts. I have this code:

```
$data = Category::with('posts')->whereHas('posts.creator', function($query) use ($filteruser) { 
    $query->where('id',=, $filteruser);
});
```

the problem is:

- I want all the categories to still return for display even if no post (after a filter) is returned. My code above doesn't do that and I can't think of how I can do it.
- if category 1 has one post that matches the filter, it will also return all the other post in the same category. I only want to show the posts that matches the filter.

Are these possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that posts have a column `user_id` which relates it to the creator record.

Try

```php
$data = Category::with(['posts' => function($query) use ($filteruser) {
        $query->with('creator')->where('user_id', $filteruser);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks. just what I needed. i thought I can only use wherehas when filtering relationship.